# How to send an email on successful test completion in django

Tags: python, django, testing

When I am running django test cases using `python manage.py test` I wnat to send an email if test cases completed successfully

As it returns 0 if success and 1 if failure, where I can get this 0 and 1 in my python script ?

I have tried using shell script then it works perfectly

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST_RESULT=`python manage.py test`
rc=$?;
if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]]
then
    echo "Tests Passed Successfully"
else
    echo "Tests failed"
fi
```

Now I want this in python script. help me in this.
Thanks

Comment: Where is the email part in your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import subprocess
ret = subprocess.call(['python', 'manage.py', 'test'])
if ret == 0:
    print("Tests Passed Successfully")
else:
    print("Tests failed")
```

Comment: @user3513758 If this answer has solved your problem, please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write another Python script to generate and send the email(s).

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST_RESULT=`python manage.py test`
rc=$?;
if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]]
then
    python sendemail.py Success
else
    python sendemail.py Failure
fi
```

See the `email` documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email-examples.html

Comment: Yes I know this, but I want to get this in python script I don't want to run .sh file.

Comment: Since I don't know what the contents of your `manage.py` look like, I'd say that the answer given by @nwk is your best bet if you want to run a Python file rather than a bash script (though the overall effect is the same).

Comment: Oh I didn't see the above answer, yes you are write , Thank you